# Как получить JSON файл и распасить его?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Добрый день. У меня имеется json файл в хранящийся на компе, как его можно прочитать и распарсить с помощью JS(XMLHttpRequest), чтобы в дальнешем использовать? к примеру он находиться "/home/user/Documents/project/data.json", мне необходимо его данные добавить на страницу проекта?

```
function load() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.timeout = 1000;

    xhr.responseType = 'json';

    xhr.open('GET', '/home/ilya/Documents/for_job/data');

    xhr.send()

}

console.log(load());
```

Вот функция, которая получает возвращает распарсенный JSON, мне необходимо просто получить, хотя бы для того чтобы просомтреть, чтобы потом использовать, но я получаю 'undefined', да и еще одно, веб-сервер не развернут.

Comment: А что именно не получается сделать ? Загрузить файл? Вроде же все просто в вашем случае. Если файл находится вне папки сайта, то сделайте способ его "залить" на сайт (через input type=file например), а потом пропустите содержимое через парсер.

Comment: Добавил некоторые обьяснения, и код.

Comment: @ИльяОлегович https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_return.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, уже решили задачу своими силами или нет, но в общем вот - я тут два дня колупал интернет в поисках решения, которое не потребовало бы сервера или использования какой-нибудь библиотеки и так ничего и не нарыл. Тянуть ради этого вопроса библиотеку смысла нет, поэтому воспользовался `Open Server`, советую и вам настроить какой-нибудь домашний серверок, хотябы ради упрощения таких ситуаций.

```
var DATA;

function getFile (fileName) {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', fileName);

    request.onloadend = function() {

        parse(request.responseText);
    }

    request.send();
}

getFile('json/data.json'); //путь к файлу

function parse(obj) {

    DATA = JSON.parse(obj);

    console.log(DATA);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, дело в том что я тоже искал кучу вариантов, и просто через js не срататывает, а вот jQuery хоть и ругается на ломаный xml но выводит! Но все равно спасибо огромное!